# Bitcoins didn't arrive to new wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core

I use Bitcoin-Qt. Decided to make another wallet and transfer some bitcoins there. Wanted to give that wallet to my friend as a gift. What I did was:

1. renamed wallet.dat file to 1_wallet.dat
2. started Bitcoin-Qt it created new wallet.dat file
3. copied address of new wallet
4. renamed wallet.dat to 2_wallet.dat and 1_wallet.dat back to wallet.dat
5. transferred some bitcoins to new wallet address

finally after transaction was confirmed I still didn't see bitcoins in a new wallet. What I did wrong? Is it possible to get back these bitcoins?

Comment: Have you tried starting bitcoin with the `-rescan` command line option?

Comment: cdecker should probably post that as an answer, that's my best guess too. If it was confirmed, it is irrevocably in that second address.

Comment: And just to make sure, ... your client is in sync as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing all block chain and retrieving it again solved this problem. I guess -rescan should help too.